# when running 'npm run watch' in the atom terminal, i get the error message in the picture below. how can this be resolved

Tags: node.js, npm, atom-editor

[npm run watch error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9Dk8.png)

Codingphase-starterkit is imported from github if that is any help.

[package.json screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Zoru.png)

[package.json screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7dkU.png)

Comment: Could you provide some code? What does your package.json look like?

Comment: hi, I have aded 2 screenshots of package.json for you to see

Comment: Any ideas? ive been stuck all day haha